Android gradle cache in Azure DevOps
I am trying to cache Gradle between runs on Azure Pipelines. My goal is to generate a build on the main branch, cache Gradle, and then use this cache when running pipelines for feature branches, allowing them to run faster
I tried this one but not working between runs of pipelines
steps:
  - task: Cache@2
    inputs:
      key: 'gradle | "$(Agent.OS)"
      restoreKeys: |
        gradle | "$(Agent.OS)"
        gradle | '*'
      path: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/.gradle'
    displayName: 'Cache Gradle'


What exactly does it mean "not working between runs of pipelines"? Is there any error? Could you please share more code that allow us to reproduce the issue?

Also, see the following code sample for Gradle.


My goal is to generate a build on the main branch, cache Gradle, and then use this cache when running pipelines for feature branches

Currently, Azure DevOps doesn't support sharing caches between different branches.
According to Cache isolation and security,

To ensure isolation between caches from different pipelines and different branches, every cache belongs to a logical container called a scope. On cache save (at the end of the job), a cache is written to the scope representing the pipeline and branch.

The caches created when building on main branch is scoped to main branch and can't be accessed when running on other branches.

As a workaround, it's suggested to create a cache build for each of your feature branches.
If you want to share caches between branches, you can submit a feature request on Developer Community and share the link of it here. So that others who want the same feature request can follow it and submit a vote to help increase the priority.

Hello, thank you for your help. i will suggest this on developer community if i couldn't find any solution but for now, I can now share cache across runs but I’m facing an issue where the Gradle cache task is not using these files that downloaded from another run and instead generates new ones. Could you help me with this?

Or how to make build task use cached gradle files


"share cache across runs"- Do you use the suggestion shared by @Bright Ran-MSFT? 2. "where the Gradle cache task is not using these files that downloaded from another run and instead generates new ones." - Do you mean that the cache task created a new cache? Why do you think the pipeline didn't use files that downloaded from another run?


The cache can be used to shared files between runs only for the same pipeline. you cannot share files between pipelines using cache.
Within the same pipeline, you can share cache between runs that triggered for different branches, but you cannot share cache generated by run triggered for pull requests (PR) to that for target branches of the PR.
For more details, see "Pipeline caching".

To share files between pipelines, you can use pipeline artifacts. For example, if you want to pass files from pipelineA to pipelineB, you can do like as below:

In pipelineA, use the PublishPipelineArtifact@1 task to publish the files as an artifact.
steps:
# Some steps to generate and copy the files to the directory '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'.
. . .

# Publish the files as an artifact from the directory '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'. 
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    artifact: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'


In the pipelineB:

Set the pipelineA as a Pipelines resource.
Use the download task to download the artifact from the pipelines resource (pipelineA).

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: pipeA
    source: pipelineA

steps:
- download: pipeA
  artifact: drop





Hello, thank you for your help. I tried your approach, and it worked; I can now access files from another pipeline. However, I’m facing an issue where the Gradle cache task is not using these files that downloaded from another run and instead generates new ones. Could you help me with this?

The task that i wrote:   bold `- download: pipeA
artifact: gradle-cache
displayName: 'Download Gradle Cache from Main Branch Pipeline'

task: Cache@2
displayName: Cache Gradle files
inputs:
key: 'gradle | "$(Agent.OS)"'
restoreKeys: |
gradle | "$(Agent.OS)"
path: $(GRADLE_USER_HOME)
cacheHitVar: GRADLE_CACHE_HIT
rolling: true`


Or how to make build task use cached gradle files

@KerollosRagaie, The download task has downloaded the required artifact files from another pipeline run into the working directory of current pipeline run. Generally, the artifact files from another pipeline run will be downloaded into the directory "$(Pipeline.Workspace)/<pipeline resource identifier>/<artifact name>". you can directly access/use the downloaded files from this directory. The Cache task is not needed.
